# How to initialize a class through an interface

Tags: c++, gnu

I have a C++ class (MyClass) that's accessed using an interface (MyClassInterface). The class will be compiled into a library and the interface will be used as the header file.

My problem is initializing the class. Here is the code that will explain better:

```
// myclassinterface.h
#ifndef MYINTERFACE_H
#define MYINTERFACE_H

class MyClassInterface
{
public:
    virtual void sayHello() = 0;
};

#endif
```

```
// myclass.h
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include "myclassInterface.h"

class MyClass : MyClassInterface
{
public:
    void sayHello();
};

#endif
```

```
// myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>

void MyClass::sayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from MyClass!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "myclassinterface.h"

int main()
{
    MyClassInterface *myClass = new MyClass(); // This doesn't compile ( error: expected type-specifier before 'MyClass')

    myClass->sayHello();
    delete myClass;
    return 0;
}
```

How should I instantiate the class?

I also tried:
MyClassInterface *myClass = new MyClassInterface(); (error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MyClassInterface')

I have similar code working for a Windows dll where I can initialize it as follows:

```
typedef MyClassInterface *(*DEF)(void);
DEF createInstance = (DEF)::GetProcAddress(hdl, "createInstance");
MyClassInterface = createInstance();
```

This code I need to compile in Linux

Comment: The library needs to provide some facility for creating such objects. How you design that facility depends on what the library does and how it does it, but unless you want to expose the concrete class it will be in the form of some kind of function.

Comment: You need to include `myclass.h` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: `class MyClass : MyClassInterface` ==> `class MyClass : public MyClassInterface`, otherwise you cannot assign a `MyClass *` to a `MyClassInterface *`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I do not want to expose all the private functions, that's why I only want to include the interface header file.

Comment: Then how can `MyClass` be recognized as a type name in `main.cpp`?

Comment: In Windows I can initialise it using something like:
typedef myInterface *(*DEF)(void);
DEF createInstance = (DEF)::GetProcAddress(hdl, "createInstance");

myInterface = createInstance();
I would like to do something similar in linux

Comment: If there already is a creation function, why don't you just expose it? Why jump through the hoops of `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: @knorpot Seems like you need to write  a factory method in `MyClassInterface`. Something like this `class MyClassInterface { static MyClassInterface* create(); ... };`

Comment: *"Here is the code that will explain better"* -- better than not explaining at all, but not better than explaining with words. You should describe the scenario in your text, then provide code to fill in the missing pieces. At least tell us what to focus on. (I think you meant to focus on "creating a `MyClass` object without exposing `myclass.h`". Build that into an introductory paragraph, and your question becomes ten times better.)

Comment: *"I have similar code working for a Windows dll where I can initialize it as follows:"* -- so why not follow the same pattern in your project? (Hint: It might help to write out in words what the "similar code" does. This doesn't have to be a huge writing assignment, just enough to organize your thoughts. Same principle as [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to write  a factory method in `MyClassInterface`. Something like this

```
class MyClassInterface
{ 
public:
    static MyClassInterface* create(); 
    ... 
};
```

Then you can write in `main`

```
MyClassInterface *myClass = MyClassInterface::create();
```

Comment: Thank you - this suggestion was the easiest to implement and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the default inheritance for classes is private so you won't be able to upcast from MyClass to MyClassInterface.

Making the inheritance public should fix the issue.

```
 class MyClass : public MyClassInterface{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is, you have some class `MyClass` that you wish to encapsulate from users of your library (for data hiding/api stability/etc), you plan to encapsulate those implementation details by using the interface `MyClassInterface`.

A great way to accomplish is this is by using the Pimpl ([Pointer to implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)) idiom.

**my_class.h**

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass(); // virtual here is a best practice, we're not going to be inheriting from this class anywhere in this example
    void sayHello();
private:
    class impl; // forward declare the implementation so we can use it below
    impl* m_pImpl;
};
```

**my_class.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "my_class.h"

// here we define the actual class details
class MyClass::impl {
public:
    void sayHello() {
        std::cout << "Hello from MyClass::impl\n";
    }
};

MyClass::MyClass() {
    this->m_pImpl - new MyClass::impl;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    delete this->m_pImpl;
}

void MyClass::sayHello() {
    this->m_pImpl->sayHello();
}
```

The library user then includes `my_class.h`, they get all the functions that you wish to provide through the interface, they know that a `MyClass::impl` class exists, but nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is something I will definitely remember for future reference or if I run into more issues with the current project.